# Why does a Python program get faster the more times it is run?

Tags: python

This isn't a problem, I'm just curious. In Atom, after running numerous tests, I realized that each python programs I created ran faster the more times they were run, (they did reach a certain equilibrium after a few runs), and I was just wondering why this happens. The programs weren't huge, (not more than 100 lines) so my best guess is the time change can be explained by the initial construction of the variables and general setup, but I'm not sure.

For background information, the way I'm getting my times is by using the "script" package by rgbkrk, which handles the output and records the time. I think the code is irrelevant due to the numerous different types of tests all yielding the same result, so here are just some example times:

Finished in 0.641s
Finished in 0.257s
Finished in 0.06s
Finished in 0.049s
Finished in 0.049s
Finished in 0.058s

I'm not entirely sure why this happens, so an explanation would be helpful. Thanks.

EDIT: Code isn't required, the same thing happens even without any code. I opened Atom and ran an empty file a few times, and the same thing happened.(The run time got faster after the first run).

Comment: We reaaaaaaaally need to see some code if we're to have any hope of investigating this.

Answer (score 1):

A surprising amount of apparent performance can be traced to how the particular operating system you're running on decides how to cache blocks from (relatively slow) disk in memory. On first run, nothing will be cached. On subsequent runs, depending on what contends for operating system disk cache in the interim, more will be cached. When you run again, not having to do to disk is a big performance win.

What you'll probably find is that if you wait a while, and run some other programs that are disk hungry, the next run of your python code will be slower.